# Basic Css Floating Query without using negative margins

Tags: css, css-float, margin

I have got a basic question , I have got a menu box in which there are two sections , right -text section and left text section , but I cant layout both horizontally as shown in the image , i want both to be aligned in horizontally without using negative margins.[image]

Css used:

```
<div id="Menu">
<div class="Menu-Left-Text">This<br />is the  <br />section for<br />left text.</div>
<div class="Menu-Right-Text">This<br />is the  <br />section for<br />right text.</div>
</div>

#Menu .Menu-Left-Text
{
margin-left: 9px; 
padding-top: 9px; 
font-size: 16pt;
font-family: 'ITC Avant Garde Gothic';
font-weight: bolder;
width: 189px;


  }
  #Menu .Menu-Right-Text
 {
float:right;
font-family: 'Times New Roman' , Times, serif;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.Menu-Left-Text { float: left; width: 50%; }
.Menu-Right-Text { margin-left: 50%; }
#Menu { overflow: auto; }
```

Using the above means that there'll be *something* in the flow of the page inside your `#Menu`, meaning your `#Menu` will have a height that's affected by its content. That'll allow you to add a background colour / image to `#Menu` that will actually work.

Or, if you don't care about it working in IE7 or lower:

```
#Menu { display: table; }
#Menu > div { display: table-cell; }
```

This has the benefit of both sides taking equal amount of space, as well as the all of the content affecting the height of the `#Menu`

Comment: which is the best way to do , the one which u suggested or the one using float :right nd left property

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain the benefits of this approach over using only floats.

Answer (score 1):

Try write float:left in Menu-Left-Text class. so your new css becomes :

```
 #Menu .Menu-Left-Text {
    margin-left: 9px; 
    padding-top: 9px; 
    font-size: 16pt;
    font-family: 'ITC Avant Garde Gothic';
    font-weight: bolder;
   width: 189px;
  float:left;
```

}

#Menu .Menu-Right-Text
   {
     float:right;

```
 font-family: 'Times New Roman' , Times, serif;

 font-weight: bold;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/patonar/Br2sQ/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!-- Head -->
<title></title>
<style>
#Menu .Menu-Left-Text
{
float:left;
margin-left: 9px; 
padding-top: 9px; 
font-size: 16pt;
font-family: 'ITC Avant Garde Gothic';
font-weight: bolder;
width: 189px;


  }
#Menu .Menu-Right-Text
{
float:right;
margin-right: 9px; 
padding-top: 9px; 
font-size: 16pt;
font-family: 'Times New Roman' , Times, serif;
font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Menu">
<div class="Menu-Left-Text">This<br />is the  <br />section for<br />left text.</div>
<div class="Menu-Right-Text">This<br />is the  <br />section for<br />right text.</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```